# javascript code not working in file but works well in console log almost every code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JavaScript code is not working when I run it from a file but it works in the console log and it happens almost every time whenever I test a JavaScript code. I am new to JavaScript so it is hard for me to understand what is going on. It would be great if I got to know what is the problem.

```js
var slideIndex=0;
var slide;
function showSlides(n){
  var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
 if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);    
}
function nextslide(position){
 slideIndex+=position;
  if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   else if(slideIndex<1){slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
         slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

}
showSlides();
```

```css
.slideshow-container{
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
}
.mySlides{
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 display:none;
   transition: all 0.6s ease; 
}
.myslides img{
 height:100%;
}
.myslides h2{
    color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left:15%;
 font-size:40px;
}

.myslides p{
    color: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top:38%;
    left: 15%;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
.prev{
 cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    top:35%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    float: left;
}
.next{
 cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    top:35%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    float:right;
}
.next:hover {
    color: #1ABC9C;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius:16px 43px 39px 21px;
    width: 35px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px;
}

.prev:hover{
   color: #1ABC9C;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 40px 16px 16px 38px;
    width: 35px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 12px 1px;
}
.slider_btn{
 font-size:20px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family:"MS Serif", "New York", serif;
 cursor:pointer;
 outline:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
    left: 15%;
}
.slider_find{
 margin-left:11%;
}
.slider_btn:hover{
 background:#1ABC9C;
 color:whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container"><!--slider starts-->

      <div class="mySlides mySlides-2 fade showing" style="display:block;">
        <img src="assets/pexels-photo-355988.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        <h2>Elegant Design</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mySlides fade showing">
        <img src="assets/iPhone-Text-Monitoring-on-Apple-Devices-Yes-And-So-Much-More.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <h2>Standard Coding</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sitvoluptatem </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mySlides fade showing">
        <img src="assets/pexels-photo-168765.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        <h2>Responsive Layout</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem </p>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="nextslide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="nextslide(1)">&#10095;</a>
       <a href="#"><button class="slider_btn contact  active ">Contact Us</button></a>
       <a href="#"><button class="slider_btn slider_find ">Find More</button></a>
      
      </div><!--slider ends-->
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console when you attach a file

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you add the JS file in the `<head>`... when the file loads, it runs `showSlides();` and since the DOM is not ready, nothing is initialized. Are you familiar with jQuery's `$('document").ready(function() {});`? If not, try adding the javascript file at the bottom of the <body>

Comment: just write alert in javascript file and attach it in your file if it is working then javascript file is attached properly. now you can check you code. one more thing i want to tel you the position of your script tag I think you are including you  js file in head.

Comment: javascript is in seperate file  .then where i can js file

Comment: thanks @vyx.ca it is working now just atteched script in bottom .

Comment: @luckyadav javascript file is your js file. whenever you want javascript from seperate file you are saving your file with.js extension

Comment: @luckyyadav great. If you want to add your scripts in the head, you need to wrap your code in jquery's document ready function. Here's a tutorial : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/